# Finding closest item in df2 for every item in df1

Tags: python, pandas

If `df` looks like

```
    row col     value
0     7   G        96
1     3   C        43
2     7   H        44
3     7   J        97
4     8   I        90
...
```

and `q` is

```
    row col    value
0     2   C      foo
1     8   F    bravo
2     9   F  charlie
3     2   D      bar
4     2   E      qux
...
```

The below code serves the purpose but is too slow. How can I optimize this to run faster ? It takes ~ 45 seconds when `len(df) = 25000`. I need to solve for when `len(df) >= 1e6`.

```
def foo(a):
    try:
        fxlter = q.loc[(q.row == a.row) & (q.col < a.col)]
        return q.loc[fxlter.col.idxmax()].value
    except ValueError:
        return None

df['foo'] = df.nodes.apply(foo)
```

*(The purpose is to match the column name and row name to the value in a generic way by finding the closest row label in q for every item in df)*

[image]

Desired output:

```
    row col  value      foo
0     7   G     96    alpha
1     3   C     43      foo
2     7   H     44    alpha
3     7   J     97    alpha
4     8   I     90    bravo
5     3   E     58      foo
6     8   H     95    bravo
7     7   I     49    alpha
8     3   D     22      foo
9     8   J     55    bravo
```

Comment: What's you desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('col'), 
                    q.sort_values('col'), 
                    on='col', 
                    by='row', 
                    allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Comment: Oh super. I was unaware of `merge_asof`. I am going to try it right now.

Comment: @Vishal - Testing now, in same data get same ooutoput, in another not, need more testing.

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Searching a bit suggests that the `on` label must be a numeric. From the docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html: *Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. The data MUST be ordered. Furthermore this must be a numeric column, such as datetimelike, integer, or float. On or left_on/right_on must be given.*

Comment: @Vishal - So need `(q.col < a.col)` ? There is not swapped column `col` and `row` columns?

Comment: I don't follow the question. What I did was convert the col from an alpha to a numeric value and then it worked. I'd have preferred being able to do a `df['foo'] = <function>` instead of the merged dataframe but that is a minor inconvenience. Thank you.

Comment: @Vishal - Not sure if understand, can you explain more? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Poorly phrased question. Will post new SO question once I figure out how to ask it. Thanks. :-)